# masking input text field with asterisk (*) using Jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Masking input text field with asterisk (*) using Jquery or javascript.
Can anybody give the solution for this.

I have searched a lot and not getting any answer.

Even tried javascript,jquery with pure coding asterisk is coming . The problem is: I'm not able to get the proper value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var val1="",val2="",val3,x,x1,i,asc;

        $("#psw").keyup(function(){

            //val1=val1+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

            val1=$("#psw").val().toString();                
            asc=val1.charCodeAt(val1.length-1);

            if((asc>=97 && asc<=122) || (asc>=65 && asc<=90))
            {
                val2=val2+val1[val1.length-1];              //actual value
            }
            //setInterval(function(){},700);


            //alert(val1);

            //val1=val1+String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

            x=val1.length;  

            x1="";  
            for(i=0;i<x;i++)
            {
                x1=x1+"*";
            }   
            //$("#psw").val("");

            $("#psw").val(x1);


        });

        $("#psw").keydown(function(){
            val3="";
            for(i=0;i<val2.length-1;i++)
            {
                    val3=val3+val2[i];
            }
            val2=val3;

        });
```

Final value which user will enter in textbox with `id="psw"` will be stored in `val2` according to this code.But proper value not coming because of `keyup` and `keydown` latency problem.

Is there any alternate solution.

Comment: just use a [password field](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.password.html) that will do it without you writing any code

Comment: yeah, did you just try `<input type="password">`?

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle

Comment: Wheels aren't made to be reinvented.

Answer (score 2):

You know, `input` has a `password` type, just use it, instead of create yours!

```
<input type="password" />
```

Comment: man our task is to mask password dots with asterisk or simple input text field with asterisk..<input type="password"> i know..I am not working as a Software Engineer ina company just to know what is <input type="password">.